# Restore NON-SVV backup in db2 dpf

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I  took non-svv online backup of a DPF database (6 nodes):

- catalog Node 0 partition backup starts at 6Am and completed at 7AM
- Node 1 partition backup starts at 7AM and completed at 8AM,
- Node 2 partition backup starts at 8AM and completed at 9AM,
- Node 3 partition backup starts at 9AM and completed at 10AM,
- Node 4 partition backup starts at 10AM and completed at 11AM,
- Node 5 partition backup starts at 11AM and completed at 12PM

Now I have to restore this backup to another sever. I am going to use  `rollforward to end of logs and complete` with the overflowpath (containing logs from the `logtarget` used in the restore command).

So my questions are :

1. New restored database will be consistent?
2. If yes, till what time it will have the consistency (6AM, 7AM or 12PM )?

Below are the commands used :

```
db2_all "db2 backup db db1 online compress"

db2_all '<<+0< db2 restore db db1 taken at <timestamp> into db11 logtarget /tmp/logtar

db2_all '<<-0< db2 restore db db1 taken at <timestamp> into db11 logtarget /tmp/logtar


db2 rollforward db db11 to end of logs and stop overflow log path /tmp/logtar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using logs from the LOGTARGET on the restores won't be enough. You will need to manually copy logs for all nodes up to time when the final node finishes its backup. (i.e., 12pm)

Then when you do the rollforward, it will bring all your nodes on the new system up to that time.

Comment: ok.... it means if i will do rollforward to end of logs in my case... the command will not get successful?

Comment: If you have only the logs that are stored in the backup images, Db2 should be preventing you from doing the ROLLFORWARD STOP step.